# C Dynamically allocated a struct in an array that is inside another struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct

So to try to sum this up nicely, I have a main struct that is a catalog, it contains a counter(of the books it has), the capacity(total number of books it can support, can also grow), and an array of pointers that point to another struct that contains the book information.

```
typedef struct BooksInStock{
    int id;
    char title[MAX_TITLE];  // 38 Characters
    char author[MAX_AUTHOR]; // 20 Characters
    double level;
    int words;
}Books;


typedef struct Stock {
    Books *b;
    int count;
    int capacity;
} Stock;
```

The exact valgrind error is:

```
==23844== Invalid read of size 4
==23844==    at 0x401418: idComp (catalog.c:27)
==23844==    by 0x4E6FC62: msort_with_tmp.part.0 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==23844==    by 0x4E6FBD7: msort_with_tmp.part.0 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==23844==    by 0x4E6FFB6: qsort_r (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==23844==    by 0x401AE3: listAll (catalog.c:168)
==23844==    by 0x400C13: main (reading.c:73)
==23844==  Address 0x6e61724674666172 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I am assuming this is because I am not allocating my structs/array properly, but I haven't had to dynamically allocate an array of structs inside another struct before and I believe I am confusing myself.

EDIT: I was allocating the memory wrong see: [C printing extremely weird values with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508002/c-printing-extremely-weird-values-with-printf)

EDIT:
As pointed out I forgot the method that calls idComp

```
void listAll(Catalog *cat)
{ // cat is just the catalog of books that have been read in already
    qsort(cat->b, cat->count, sizeof( Books ), idComp);  // idComp is called here
    if (cat->count == 0) {
        printf("No matching books");
    } else {
        printf("%5s %38s %20s %5s %7s", "ID", "Title", "Author", "Level", "Words");
        for (int i = 0; i < cat->count; i++) {
            printf("%5d %38s %20s %5.1f %7d", cat->b[i].id, cat->b[i].title,
            cat->b[i].author, cat->b[i].level, cat->b[i].words);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You didn't disclose how `levelComp` is called. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MikeCAT unfortunately there is a limit on how much of this I can actually post, it is a school assignment I just came here because I haven't been able to get a response from my teacher in 2 days.

Comment: That's the comparator function for `qsort()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes it is, or at least it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat->b` points at an array of `Books`, so what are passed to comparision function of `qsort` are pointers to `Books`, not pointers to pointers to `Books`.

Threfore, the `idComp` function should be like this:

```
static int idComp( const void *aptr, const void *bptr )
{
  const Books *a = aptr;
  const Books *b = bptr;

  if ( a->id < b->id )
    return -1;
  if ( a->id > b->id )
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```