# C printing extremely weird values with printf

Tags: arrays, c, parsing, struct, printf

I am rewriting this post because I managed to figure out the problem.  The problem with my extremely broken output was due to an improper dynamic memory allocation.

Basically I needed to allocate memory for an array of pointers that pointed to structs, but the array itself was nested inside of another struct and the nesting confused me slightly and I ended up over complicating it.

So I had a struct named Catalog, that my array was in and that array pointed to another struct named Books.

When I originally allocated memory for it I was only allocated memory for an array, not an array of pointers:

```
catalog->arrayP = malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof( Books );
// But I should have done this:
catalog->arrayP = (Books *) malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof( Books );
// That first (Books *) was extremely important
```

The second issue I was having was that when I was trying to update the memory to allow for more books I was actually decreasing it:

```
catalog->arrayP = realloc(catalog->arrayP, 2 * sizeof( catalog->arrayP));
// I did this thinking it would just increase the memory to twice that of what it currently was, but it didn't
cataloc->capacity = catalog->capacity * 2;
catalog->arrayP = realloc(catalog->arrayP, catalog->capacity * sizeof( catalog->arrayP));
```

So whenever I needed to grow my array of pointers I ended up just allocating enough memory for 2 books rather than double the current.

Comment: @user3121023 I attempted the change you suggested but it now causes a Segmentation fault :-(

Comment: @user3121023 There is a malloc but it does use Books, I'll update the question to include the constructor for the catalog

Comment: I suggest you try running valgrind's memcheck tool on your program. You could use [this tutorial](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Comment: @einpoklum So I should be using sizeof( Books ) instead and I may have a memory leak elsewhere?

Comment: @JoshAvery: Possibly. This is general advice when you're seeing garbled data you didn't expect.

Comment: @einpoklum I did what you suggested and I am getting several errors from Valgrind.  They seem to be centered at two different lines of code either: `if (bookID == cat->b[i].id) {` on line 108(made a comment on code) and `strcpy(cat->b[cat->count].title, title);` on line 124, both are Invalid write of size 4 or 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Frankenstein; Or, The Modern Prometh..Shelley, Mary Woll.
```

Your printing results kind of give away the answer. You forgot the null terminator on your strings and printf invaded the next field until reached the null terminator.

In the following fields it couldn't find and invaded even more stuff.

Here's a minimal example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct test{
  char test[37]; // space for 36 chars + null
  char test2[16]; // space for 15 chars + null
};
int main(void) {
  struct test Test;
  strcpy(Test.test, "randomrandomrandomrandomrandomrandom"); // Copy the 37 bytes
  strcpy(Test.test2, "notnotnotnotnot"); // Copy the 16 bytes
  //Replace null terminator with trash for demonstration purposes
  Test.test[36] = '1'; // replaces 37th byte containing the terminator (\0) with trash
  printf("%38s", Test.test); // should print randomrandomrandomrandomrandomrandom1notnotnotnotnot
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That did indeed fix my issue of it continuing to print beyond what it should but unfortunately I made a mistake when originally making the post.  I did not include the entire output, which was a HUGE mistake on my part since if you look at the output now you should see my real problem

Comment: The error looks exactly the same for me. Still missing nullpointers.

Comment: the Output text is missing null pointers? And that is what is causing the output to be so horribly broken? I don't even know where I would be putting more null terminators I only have 2 strings I am printing. I attempted to double check that all the Title and Author strings were null terminated, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Oh, I see, the exclamation on Alice's title. Hmm, I guess you ended up overwriting things. 
Can't really help with that without debugging. I would try removing that quicksort.

My bad, null terminators, not pointers. =x

Comment: BTW, did you increase the MAX_TITLE and MAX_AUTHOR sizes to make space for the null terminator?

Comment: Yes, I guess I forgot to update the post here but I added 1 space to each to make room for the extra character